# Unity c# how to properly use GetComponent

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am in no way a coding novice but I just picked up unity and I'm trying "get it"

My question involves this code. it is not part of an active project. it is simply an attempt to understand the system

```
private SpriteRenderer beans2;

public Sprite beanimmage;
// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
beans2 = gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();   

beans2.sprite = beanimmage;
}
```

from what I understand this code allows me to manipulate the SpriteRenderer of the game object this code is attached to by assigning it to beans2 and then changing the Sprite of beans2 to beanimmage and works fine in the system

My question is -
Is their a way to assign beans2 to the spriterenderer of a diffident game object? The object i have this code attached to is just a game object called test is their a way to assign the beans2 variable to the SpriteRenderer of my test2 object instead ?

something like this ?

```
beans2 = test2.gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
beans2 = gameObject.test2.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The GetComponent() Function is apart of every gameobject so to get components on other gameobjects you need to reference that gameobject in a variable, something like this:

```
public GameObject test2;
private SpriteRenderer test2Renderer;
public Sprite beanImage;

void Awake()
{
    test2Renderer = test2.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
    test2Renderer.sprite = beanImage;
}
```

Alternatively, you can just get the component of the test2 object from the inspector because you are using public variables. To do this make a sprite renderer variable field and make it public so it is shown in the inspector, then drag the test2 object into the field and it will automatically get the sprite renderer component off that object.

Finally, you could also just do this with one field. This method would be used when you only want to access the GameObject and nothing else:

```
public GameObject test2;
public Sprite beansImage;

void Awake
{
    test2.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = beansImage;
}
```

Any way works and you should do it the second way if you want to work with public variables and rely on the inspector but if you only need the gameobject then go with method 3. Method 1 is probably the best way to do it so you can change the sprite later if you want.